8 input True XOR
(2nd try to post correct image...) As has been posted here in a previous query, when XOR gates are cascaded the output now is not XOR.
I thought up this solution for an 8-input XOR which passed a truth table check, but I wonder if anyone has tried it and found some quirk that makes it unusable:


Do you see an issue in the design or do you just want some feedback? BTW, is the definition of true XOR that there should be only 1 input out of the 8 that is logic 1?

I know Boolean defines XOR as only high if odd number of inputs high, but taking the English definition of truly "Exclusive" I think this circuit indeed only outputs high if only one of 8 is high, that was the aim of the circuit.

You did not answer my first question though. Otherwise, the circuit should work as you expect. I don't see any issues

Since you don't provide the truth table to test your claim that "it passed the truth table check", one can only assume that yes, it does what you think it does.
The only thing you may have overlooked is that the overall output (XOR pin 3) may transition a few times following a change in inputs, while the various signals propagate through the system.
As long as this is OK for you, and the delay from signal propagation is acceptable, then this whole circuit will be OK. Everything depends on what comes after this module, the "user" of this signal, about which you tell us nothing.

H  Simon, Sai, This circuit is part of a multi-input audio source selector, and the purpose was to detect and inhibit multiple source selection.  Not having integrated any BCD decoder ICs other than 7-segment ones years ago I didn't know if they had any quirky behaviors...It would have been more trivial perhaps using a uPC but I was hoping to execute the design in just a few 4000/74C00 packages.  Thank you for your time!
